# Integrate an Xpath statement into a Linq query of a WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xpath

Hello and thanks in advance for the help.
I have a sql table hosted on a server that has two columns: ID(int), server_info(xml)
The xml entries in this table look like this:

```
<ServerID>11</ServerID><GroupID /><ParentID>15</ParentID><ServerName>IAProd1</ServerName><User>admin</User><UID>123</UID><PWD>password</PWD><Domain>TestDomain</Domain><Location>Left</Location>
```

This table is represented within my Silverlight application as a ADO.Net data entity data model. I want to have a parameterized query called via the WCF service that takes an Id number and finds the children in the server table based on their parent id value which is embedded within the xml of their server_info column. 
On the sql server I can do this using the following query with an xpath statment:

```
<!--uses xpath statement in the where clause:(server_info.value('(ServerID)[1]', 'int') = 11) --> 
    SELECT     ID, server_info
    FROM         tbl_server_xml
    WHERE     (server_info.value('(ServerID)[1]', 'int') = 11)
```

Currently my query method looks something like this:

```
public List<tbl_server_xml> getChildServers(int parentId)
        {
            //create instance of Ado.Net entity
            xMonitorXMLTestDBEntities db = new xMonitorXMLTestDBEntities();
            var item = from entry in db.tbl_server_xml
                       where //need assistance with the where clause
                       select entry;

        }
```

I have not been able to figure out how to do the equivalent with just a linq query in the service method or a way to integrate xpath statements into Linq queries. Is there a way to do this or am I going about this wrong? Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `server_info` is not a valid XML document content because it  have no root element. But with a simple trick you could write your query like this

```
 var item = from entry in db.tbl_server_xml
                       where XDocument.Parse("<Root>" + entry.server_info + "</Root>").
                             XPathSelectElements("//ServerID[1]").Single().Value == "11"
                       select entry;
```

or using plain Linq to XML

```
var item = from entry in db.tbl_server_xml
                           where XDocument.Parse("<Root>" + entry.server_info + "</Root>").
                                 Descendants("ServerID").First().Value == "11"
                           select entry;
```

Comment: thank you for the response, and that makes sense looking at it, I guess I am more inexperienced with xml in C# then I realized. However, when I try either of the methods you suggest I get the following error:
 //LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement] Descendants(System.Xml.Linq.XName)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Is there a library I need to include/using statement I need in order to utilize xml classes within a data entity query? thanks again for the help

Comment: yes, you should add reference to `System.Xml.Linq` if it not referenced yet and add `using System.Xml.XPath;` and `using System.Xml.Linq;` to your source file

Comment: I have those references and the query is still not recognized. A reply to this post:[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103620/entity-framework-query-xml[link] suggests that neither of the Entity Framework's query languages (LINQ to Entities and eSQL) directly support nested XML queries. Are you certain that is not the case?

Comment: Really, i didn't know about this feature before and tested your question on simple `List<string>` instead of real `Entity`, but now I was convinced that it's not so simple. The simplest way now is to get all items via `var items = (from entry in db.tbl_server_xml).AsEnumerable();` and call `Where` method as before `var item = items.Where(entry => XDocument.Parse("<Root>" + entry.server_info + "</Root>").XPathSelectElements("//ServerID[1]").Single().Value == "11");`

Comment: Or you can create model function, of course, as Alex James [recommends](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1104689/1177288)

Comment: Yeah, I had gone ahead and just retrieved all the times and then sorted from there. I ran into some issues with loading them into a XDocument but I think I have it sorted now. Thanks for the help