# EF4 wrapper function to get value from XML field

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF4, dotnet 4. I want to create an edmx function to help me get xml values from an xml column (SQLServer 2008R2). My question is basically the same as posted on [Entity Framework Query Xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103620/entity-framework-query-xml)

I started off by creating the function in my C# file as such:

```
    [System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmFunction("ModelNamespace", "String_XmlField")]
    public static String XmlField(this String data, String path)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not implemented");
    }
```

The next piece went into my edmx (correct csdl schema):

```
    <Function Name="String_XmlField" ReturnType="Edm.String">
      <Parameter Name="data" Type="Edm.String" />
      <Parameter Name="path" Type="Edm.String" />
      <DefiningExpression>
        data.value(path, "nvarchar(max)")
      </DefiningExpression>
    </Function>
```

And i'm trying to use it like this:

source = source.Where(x => x.NewData.XmlField("(//IDPat/node())[1]") == "3152");

The error i'm getting is: "An error occurred while preparing definition of the function 'ModelNamespace.String_XmlField'. See the inner exception for details.", with an inner exception with message "'value' is not a member of type 'Edm.String' in the currently loaded schemas. Near simple identifier, line 2, column 18."

I'm pretty sure the error lies in the edmx part missing in the original response, but i can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have put T-SQL command in CSDL. At the CSDL your database was abstracted and the EF does not "know" (and does not care) what your back end is. The DefiningExpression is an expression in Entity SQL - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx - and not any dialect of SQL specific to a database. At this level the string type is the type from the EDM type system (denoted as Edm.String) which does not have .value property of function. (In fact it does not have any properties or functions). If you need store specifc function defined using the dialect of Sql the database is using you need to store it in SSDL Function element - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283136(v=VS.90)