# Sql exist in Linq lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I have a table called "[PcValueSet]".

Table has the Field "[FieldValues]".

Field Values is a XML field.

Following is the the where clause on the table i use to find results.

```
WHERE [FieldValues].exist('/_DoorConfig2Page3Table/_DoorConfig2Page3Row/txtDoorDesign') = 1
```

In C# in a method i need to do a similar thing only i need to get the value of "txtDoorDesign" instead.

I have the following but im not sure how to create a similar functionality that ".exist" in sql provides nor do i know how to get the value of the element rather than the element.

```
var temp = Db.PcValueSet.Where(x => x.Company == Session.CompanyID &&
               x.FieldValues.the xml element is not null or empty).ToList();
```

So I need to find and return the value of an element inside and xml column.

Comment: I believe this is still not supported in EF6. See possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1104689/1260204. Your best bet is to created a stored proc and call it from EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you are using a `SELECT` with the given `WHERE` to retrieve your data.

Just add this as *column* to your query:

```
[FieldValues].value('(/_DoorConfig2Page3Table/_DoorConfig2Page3Row/txtDoorDesign)[1]','varchar(max)') AS txtDoorDesing
```

Your result-set will include the value of `txtDoorDesign` without losing the performance of `.exist()`.

Comment: ok thats understandable, but how do i go about converting that to a lambda expression in c#?

Comment: @lemunk Sorry, don't know... What is the type of column *FieldValues*? It's probably `string`. I suppose you'd have to cast this to `XDocument` to perform XML specific queries. I'm quite sure, that this can be done implicitly, but would have to test this myself.