# How to check the attribute value string from linq in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have a string value in column of database table :-

`<Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="322"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>782</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>`

There are multiple column with the same format.

Now I need to check ProductAttributeValue and get the data from linQ

currently I am doing by

```
var id = 782
var string = "<Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="322"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>" + id + "</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>";

var value = sometable.where(x => x.valueString == string).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there any way to get direct from linq?

Comment: There's no built-in support for it, but you can take a look at [Entity Framework Query Xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1103620/3034273) and the documentation for [User-defined function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) in EF Core (I'm guessing you're using EF Core)

Comment: What does "check ProductAttributeValue and get the data from LINQ" mean? What is wrong with what you are doing?

Comment: @NetMage I already have the value for ProductAttributeValue say 722. Now I need to get that value from list whose ProductAttributeValue in the XML is 722.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview).

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
...

var id = "Value To Find";
var str = "<Attributes><ProductAttribute ID=\"322\"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>" + id + "</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>";

var xml = XDocument.Parse(str);
var val = xml
    .Element("Attributes")
    .Element("ProductAttribute")
    .Element("ProductAttributeValue")
    .Element("Value")?.Value;
```

Since there is only 1 of each element in the xml data structure you can use `Element`, if there are multiple you can use `Elements` and operate on them as a collection.

You can filter elements like usual using Where and other extension methods.

```
var valToFind = "722";
var val = xml
    .Element("Attributes")
    .Elements("ProductAttribute")
    .Where(node => node
        .Element("ProductAttributeValue")
        ?.Element("Value")
        ?.Value == valToFind
    )
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The above will find the ProductAttribute node that has a ProductAttributeValue Value equal to the valToFind.  valToFind is a string for quick comparison against the xml string value.

Comment: This code is for the value to find. What I actually need is that I already have the value for ProductAttributeValue say 722. Now I need to get that value from list whose ProductAttributeValue in the XML is 722.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a sample that finds the ProductAttribute node who has the nested Value node with value equal to the value to find.